# Get integers from Buttons and put them to array

Tags: java, android, arrays

my buttons have random integers inside. I am creating them like this in tablelayout.

```
  private static final int  a=6;
private static final int  b=6;
private int[] ids = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
Random rand = new Random();
        private void createLayoutDynamically() {

                won = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.won);
                for ( int qq = 1; qq < a; qq++) {
                    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);

                for ( int q = 1; q < b; q++) {

                        myButton = new Button(this);

                        final int number = new Random().nextInt(9);      
                    final int rand = (ids[number]);
                        myButton.setText(""+rand);
                    myButton.setTypeface(type);
                    myButton.setId(rand);
                    myButton.setTag(rand);
                    }
    }
```

I want to put this integers from my buttons to array and then how to access these numbers in an array?

Comment: unclear what you are asking, please explain better.

Comment: get numbers from my generated buttons and put them to array.

Comment: why you don't put your random number to Array in for statement? what is the problem with that?

Comment: how to put them to array ? and then access them?

Comment: create one array, add that to your array in for statement, and get that every where you want,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need to do is to put all your reference to the buttons in an array, so each time you add them to the `TableRow` you then add them to the array of buttons.

**getting the refence of buttons:**

just iterate to the array of buttons and get each number.

**sample:**

create a global instance of arraylist of button

```
private ArrayList<Button> arrayButton;
```

add button after each iteration

```
for ( int q = 1; q < b; q++) {

                    myButton = new Button(this);

                    final int number = new Random().nextInt(9);      
                final int rand = (ids[number]);
                    myButton.setText(""+rand);
                myButton.setTypeface(type);
                myButton.setId(rand);
                myButton.setTag(rand);
               arrayButton.add(myButton);
                }
```

**getting the value of buttons**

```
iterate to all the array of button
arrayButton.get(index).getTag
```

Comment: I think you have tried to solve OP's problem in hard way, as OP need rand number there is no reason to save buttons, i think create one array of Integer is very simpler than what you post,

Comment: @shayanpourvatan I think what he mean is after he added the buttons to the TableRow. and get the number.

Comment: ok, so why he should save array of buttons? i think your answer is correct but in hard way ( if i get OP's problem right )

Comment: @shayanpourvatan it is be better and clean to just put buttons reference to the array then getting it from table everytime

Comment: private ArrayList<Button> arrayButton = new  ArrayList<Button>();
it looks like now:android.widget.Button{some text and last is #2} and this 2 value i want. How to refer to them now ? for example i want to multiply two values from this array

Comment: @JaKoZo just get the tag of button just like what I did and cast them to int and multiple them

Comment: arrayButton.get(index).getTag().toString(); why if i put 0 instead of index. it shows tag of first button. and if i put for example 2. it thorows java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 1

Comment: @JaKoZo cause you only put 1 button to the array thats why you got that error

Answer (score 0):

You can add the numbers to an `int[]` while you are creating your buttons.

```
int[] numberArray = new int[b];
private void createLayoutDynamically() {
        ...
    for ( int q = 1; q < b; q++) {
        ...
        myButton.setTag(rand);
        numberArray[q] = rand;
    }
}
```